# Passing array of string as parameter from go to C function

Tags: go, cgo

I have one C function:

```
int cgroup_change_cgroup_path(const char * path, pid_t pid, const char *const  controllers[])
```

I want to call it in go language by using cgo.
How to pass the third parameter as it accepts a C array of string.

Answer (score 4):

You can build the arrays using c helper functions and then use them.

Here is a solution to the same problem:

```
// C helper functions:

static char**makeCharArray(int size) {
        return calloc(sizeof(char*), size);
}

static void setArrayString(char **a, char *s, int n) {
        a[n] = s;
}

static void freeCharArray(char **a, int size) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
                free(a[i]);
        free(a);
}

// Build C array in Go from sargs []string

cargs := C.makeCharArray(C.int(len(sargs)))
defer C.freeCharArray(cargs, C.int(len(sargs)))
for i, s := range sargs {
        C.setArrayString(cargs, C.CString(s), C.int(i))
}
```

[golangnuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/golang-nuts/char**$20array%7Csort:relevance/golang-nuts/pQueMFdY0mk/OAX5-Fqus0UJ) post by John Barham