# Runtime error with cgo and certain string slices

Tags: go, cgo

I have stripped back a problem I have come across whilst wrapping some C code to work with golang using swig but the problem doesn't rest with swig.

I can pass in a basic string slice but as soon as I construct the slice with anything other than basic strings, I get a panic: runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer.

```
go version go1.8.5 linux/amd64
```

This is the sample code and its output

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct { char *p; int n; } _gostring_;
typedef struct { void* array; int len; int cap; } _goslice_;

void prtText(char * const *txt, int len)
{
    int i = 0;

    for ( i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
        printf("Text %d is: %s\n", i, txt[i]);
    }
}

void _wrap_printText(_goslice_ _swig_go_0) {

  _gostring_ *p;

  char **arg1 = (char **)calloc(_swig_go_0.len, sizeof(char*));
  if (arg1) {
    for (int i=0; i<_swig_go_0.len; i++) {
      p = &(((_gostring_*)_swig_go_0.array)[i]);
      arg1[i] = calloc(1,(p->n)+1);
      strncpy(arg1[i], p->p, p->n);
    }
  }
  int arg2 = _swig_go_0.len;

  prtText((char *const *)arg1,arg2);
}

*/
import "C"

func PrintText(arg1 []string) {
    C._wrap_printText(*(*C._goslice_)(unsafe.Pointer(&arg1)))
}

func main() {
    s := []string{}

    s = append(s, "blah")
    s = append(s, "hello")
    s = append(s, "again")

    ns := []string{}

    ns = append(ns, "ns: "+s[0])
    ns = append(ns, "ns: "+s[1])
    ns = append(ns, "ns: "+s[2])

    fmt.Println("type s:", reflect.TypeOf(s))
    fmt.Println("type ns:", reflect.TypeOf(ns))
    fmt.Println("s:", s)
    fmt.Println("ns:", ns)

    PrintText(s)
    PrintText(ns)
}


go build -i -x -gcflags '-N -l' main.go

./main
type s: []string
type ns: []string
s: [blah hello again]
ns: [ns: blah ns: hello ns: again]
Text 0 is: blah
Text 1 is: hello
Text 2 is: again
panic: runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer
```

As you can see, the first string slice works fine but as soon as I do anything other than basic strings, it fails. I've tried making new strings first before appending them to the slice but the problem remains.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're intentionally bypassing any safety checks. You need to properly convert your `[]string` first. See the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997786/passing-array-of-string-as-parameter-from-go-to-c-function

Comment: The runtime panics because passing pointers to Go allocated memory is not allowed. While the GC doesn't move memory (yet), it's far too easy for it to collect a value that goes out of scope as it's being passed to a C function.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically passing the raw Go pointers.
Instead, you should build `C` arrays yourself.

As a general rule, seeing `unsafe` pretty much anywhere should make you suspicious. It is rarely the right way around issues with cgo.

Using the helpers from [Passing array of string as parameter from go to C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997786/passing-array-of-string-as-parameter-from-go-to-c-function) and using them in your code:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "reflect"
)

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void prtText(char * const *txt, int len)
{
    int i = 0;

    for ( i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
        printf("Text %d is: %s\n", i, txt[i]);
    }
}

static char**makeCharArray(int size) {
        return calloc(sizeof(char*), size);
}

static void setArrayString(char **a, char *s, int n) {
        a[n] = s;
}

static void freeCharArray(char **a, int size) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
                free(a[i]);
        free(a);
}

*/
import "C"

func main() {
  s := []string{}

  s = append(s, "blah")
  s = append(s, "hello")
  s = append(s, "again")

  ns := []string{}

  ns = append(ns, "ns: "+s[0])
  ns = append(ns, "ns: "+s[1])
  ns = append(ns, "ns: "+s[2])

  fmt.Println("type s:", reflect.TypeOf(s))
  fmt.Println("type ns:", reflect.TypeOf(ns))
  fmt.Println("s:", s)
  fmt.Println("ns:", ns)

  sargs := C.makeCharArray(C.int(len(s)))
  defer C.freeCharArray(sargs, C.int(len(s)))
  for i, p := range s {
    C.setArrayString(sargs, C.CString(p), C.int(i))
  }

  nsargs := C.makeCharArray(C.int(len(ns)))
  defer C.freeCharArray(nsargs, C.int(len(ns)))
  for i, p := range ns {
    C.setArrayString(nsargs, C.CString(p), C.int(i))
  }

  C.prtText(sargs, C.int(len(s)))
  C.prtText(nsargs, C.int(len(ns)))
}
```

The output is now as expected:

```
$ ./main 
type s: []string
type ns: []string
s: [blah hello again]
ns: [ns: blah ns: hello ns: again]
Text 0 is: blah
Text 1 is: hello
Text 2 is: again
Text 0 is: ns: blah
Text 1 is: ns: hello
Text 2 is: ns: again
```

Comment: The problem is when using swig, it deals with the raw go pointers by using the same underlying type in C. I don't really understand why it all works when just using s as in my given example and fails with ns. I understand your given solution but need to now work it into the swig bindings.