# Does data race happen when using cgo?

Tags: go, can-bus, cgo, data-race

Goroutines runs in different stack for cgo and go:

> C doesn’t know anything about Go’s calling convention or growable stacks, so a call down to C code must record all the details of the goroutine stack, switch to the C stack, and run C code which has no knowledge of how it was invoked, or the larger Go runtime in charge of the program.

Is there any possiblities to  trigger data race for variables or types shared between them?

Recently, I got errors when initialize slices like:

```
package controlcan

import "C"

cReceive := make([]C.struct__CAN_OBJ, 2500)
```

or

```
package main

import "controlcan"

pReceive := make([]controlcan.CanObj, 2500)
```

Both of them complains "unexpected fault address" errors randomly:

```
unexpected fault address 0xffffffffffffffff
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0xffffffffffffffff pc=0x41c65d]

goroutine 41 [running]:
runtime.throw(0xcc969a, 0x5)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:619 +0x88 fp=0xc0428ffb38 sp=0xc0428ffb18 pc=0x42d0b8
runtime.sigpanic()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_windows.go:170 +0x13a fp=0xc0428ffb68 sp=0xc0428ffb38 pc=0x43fcca
runtime.gcMarkRootPrepare()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcmark.go:72 +0x5d fp=0xc0428ffb70 sp=0xc0428ffb68 pc=0x41c65d
runtime.gcStart(0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:1350 +0x30f fp=0xc0428ffba0 sp=0xc0428ffb70 pc=0x419b6f
runtime.mallocgc(0x10000, 0xc54660, 0xc0422ee001, 0xc0423ded60)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:803 +0x448 fp=0xc0428ffc40 sp=0xc0428ffba0 pc=0x411c48
runtime.makeslice(0xc54660, 0x9c4, 0x9c4, 0xc04202ce00, 0xc04202c000, 0x411b23)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/slice.go:61 +0x7e fp=0xc0428ffc70 sp=0xc0428ffc40 pc=0x43fffe
controlcan.Receive(0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc04267e000, 0x9c4, 0x9c4, 0x64, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /media/sf_GOPATH0/src/controlcan/controlcan.go:262 +0x75 fp=0xc0428ffd70 sp=0xc0428ffc70 pc=0xa0d795
posam/protocol/usbcan.(*Channel).receive(0xc04229d490)
        /media/sf_GOPATH0/src/posam/protocol/usbcan/usbcan.go:469 +0x536 fp=0xc0428fffd8 sp=0xc0428ffd70 pc=0xa10926
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361 +0x1 fp=0xc0428fffe0 sp=0xc0428fffd8 pc=0x457531
created by posam/protocol/usbcan.(*Channel).Start
        /media/sf_GOPATH0/src/posam/protocol/usbcan/usbcan.go:242 +0x3aa
```

**Update**

`controlcan` is a wrapper package that encapsulates functions defined in `.dll` or `.so` libraries to the ones that Golang-friendly, e.g., sending messages to, or receiving messages from CAN devices. IMO, it's really weird that data race on the statement of slice initialization, within the `controlcan` package and other packages imported it.

In the `Receive` function, the first line declares a slice called `cReceive` and I got the errors randomly as mentioned above. I think the reason of `unexpected fault address` is data race rather than memory corruption, but the resource required here is only the type `C.struct__VCI_CAN_OBJ`, not any variables. I hope I was wrong.

What's worse, the type `CanObj`, which is used in othe packages like `usbcan.go`, still possibly triggers that errors, e.g., the statement of `pReceive`. Previously, I suspected that the reason might be the constant of `2500`, since the original statement is `cReceive := make([]C.struct__VCI_CAN_OBJ, FRAME_LENGTH_OF_RECEPTION)`. But when I changed it to `2500` directly, the error occurs all the same.

controlcan.go

```
package controlcan

import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "unsafe"
)

const (
    FRAME_LENGTH_OF_RECEPTION = 2500
)

type CanObj struct { // <- accessable for other packages/goroutines
    ID         int
    TimeStamp  int
    TimeFlag   int
    SendType   byte
    RemoteFlag byte
    ExternFlag byte
    DataLen    byte
    Data       [8]byte
    Reserved   [3]byte
}

func Receive(
    devType int,
    devIndex int,
    canIndex int,
    pReceive []CanObj,
    waitTime int,
) (count int, err error) {
    cReceive := make([]C.struct__VCI_CAN_OBJ, 2500) // unexpected fault address
    cCount := C.VCI_Receive(
        C.uint(devType),
        C.uint(devIndex),
        C.uint(canIndex),
        (*C.struct__VCI_CAN_OBJ)(unsafe.Pointer(&cReceive)),
        C.uint(FRAME_LENGTH_OF_RECEPTION),
        C.int(waitTime),
    )

    // ...
}
```

usbcan.go

```
package usbcan

import "controlcan"

func (c *Channel) receive() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    for _ = range ticker.C {
        pReceive := make([]controlcan.CanObj, 2500) // unexpected fault address
        count, err := controlcan.Receive(
            c.DevType,
            c.DevIndex,
            c.CanIndex,
            pReceive,
            100,
        )
    // ...
```

**Update 2:**

I move the `cReceive` creation from Go to Cgo, stolen from [Kenny Grant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46002617/5658049), and the make-slice error of `cReceive` line is solved.

```
package controlcan

// static VCI_CAN_OBJ** makeCanObjArray(){
//     return calloc(sizeof(VCI_CAN_OBJ*), 2500);
// }
// static void freeCanObjArray(VCI_CAN_OBJ **canObjArray){
//     int i;
//     for (i=0; i<2500;i++)
//         free(canObjArray[i]);
//     free(canObjArray);
// }
import "C"

func Receive(
    devType int,
    devIndex int,
    canIndex int,
    pReceive []CanObj,
    waitTime int,
) (count int, err error) {
    cReceive := C.makeCanObjArray()
    defer C.freeCanObjArray(cReceive)
// ...
```

And I still can't figure out what happens when creating `pReceive`:

```
pReceive := make([]controlcan.CanObj, 2500)
```

```
unexpected fault address 0xffffffffffffffff
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0xffffffffffffffff pc=0x41c65d]

goroutine 28 [running]:
runtime.throw(0xcc969a, 0x5)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:619 +0x88 fp=0xc04275bc38 sp=0xc04275bc18 pc=0x42d0b8
runtime.sigpanic()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_windows.go:170 +0x13a fp=0xc04275bc68 sp=0xc04275bc38 pc=0x43fcca
runtime.gcMarkRootPrepare()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcmark.go:72 +0x5d fp=0xc04275bc70 sp=0xc04275bc68 pc=0x41c65d
runtime.gcStart(0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:1350 +0x30f fp=0xc04275bca0 sp=0xc04275bc70 pc=0x419b6f
runtime.mallocgc(0x1a000, 0xc54520, 0x1, 0xa10101)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:803 +0x448 fp=0xc04275bd40 sp=0xc04275bca0 pc=0x411c48
runtime.makeslice(0xc54520, 0x9c4, 0x9c4, 0xc0420162a0, 0x8, 0x8)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/slice.go:61 +0x7e fp=0xc04275bd70 sp=0xc04275bd40 pc=0x43fffe
posam/protocol/usbcan.(*Channel).receive(0xc04213fdc0)
        /media/sf_GOPATH0/src/posam/protocol/usbcan/usbcan.go:464 +0x4f0 fp=0xc04275bfd8 sp=0xc04275bd70 pc=0xa108e0
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361 +0x1 fp=0xc04275bfe0 sp=0xc04275bfd8 pc=0x457531
created by posam/protocol/usbcan.(*Channel).Start
        /media/sf_GOPATH0/src/posam/protocol/usbcan/usbcan.go:242 +0x3aa
```

Comment: The error says you are calling `controlcan.Recievee`, which is unknown to us. Please provide more info on what `controlcan` package is. As for data race, yes, Cgo can cause data race just like all other codes.

Comment: As for the general question, yes, of course if there is shared memory there can be race conditions.

Comment: @leafbebop @JimB Thank you! I've added some codes, and please check the **Update**, does race happen on the type `CanObj` or `C.struct_xxx` ?

Comment: You can't have a race on a type, and the `pReceive` argument isn't used in the code here, so we have no way of knowing. You are however passing a pointer to a go slice into a C function call, so it's likely that you're just corrupting the program memory and that call happens to be were things fail.

Comment: @JimB Thank you! It's true that I corrupted the program memory mistakenly by passing `SliceHeader` instead of the 1st element of array to C function, then C messed up the contiguous addresses in the memory, which are recognized as available both in Go and C. The stacktrace shows the error of memory allocation with these addresses, IMO. It's really easy to be confused, since none of them is the real place that the corruption occured. Thank you again!